# Problem in accessing Dictionary with key as True and Integer key as 1

Tags: python, dictionary, integer, boolean, key-value

MyCODE

```
   mydict={True:'Visa',2:"verified",1:'Married',(111,222):'dept1 office 2'}
   print(f"mydict.get(True)---> {mydict.get(True)}")
   print(f"mydict.get(2)---> {mydict.get(2)}")
   print(f"mydict.get(1)---> {mydict.get(1)}")
   print(f"mydict.get((111,222))---> {mydict.get((111,222))}")
```

OUTPUT

```
mydict.get(True)---> Married
mydict.get(2)---> verified
mydict.get(1)---> Married
mydict.get((111,222))---> dept1 office 2
```

My question is why mydict.get(True)---> Married ...It should be Visa right...why it happened that?

Comment: I'd avoid using `True` as a key

Comment: `True` and `1` are the same key that's why `True == 1` evaluates to `True`

Comment: U r right bro.....but thing is dictionary cannot have duplicates keys right...both key as 1 and True are giving as Married...how to access the value "visa". even though dict is taking 1 as a key.

Comment: @AMIRHAMZASHAIKH correct, print `mydict` and see what is returned.

Comment: But i need that value to accessed separately. print(mydict) will show whole key:value pairs. it shows  correctly

Comment: @AMIRHAMZASHAIKH Are you sure about that? See the example in my answer. Pretty surely, `print(mydict)` will not show both `1` and `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type is not a distinguishing factor for hashing of numeric keys in a dictionary.

The following dictionary:

```
{True:'A', 1:'B', 1.0:'C'}
```

Actually ends up being:

```
{True: 'C'}
```

because the last value updates the initial key when you provide the same key multiple times.  So, a value of 1 is considered the same whether it is a boolean, integer or float.  This is consistent with comparison operators: `True == 1 == 1.0`

If you want the distinction to be made, you'll need to either convert everything to a string or add the data type as part of the key (neither seem very good, so perhaps you'll want to use a different convention for the True key).

Answer (score 2):

One of the great show-effects in Python, based on the fact that you cannot have multiple equal keys (as in `==`-equal)

```
>>> {1: "one", True: "true", 1.0: "ok", 0.99999999999999999: "weird"}
{1: 'weird'}  #
```

If the same key (wrt to equality testing via `==`) is encountered multiple times, the first key "wins", but the last value:

```
>>> d = {1: 2}
>>> d[True] = 5
>>> d
{1: 5}

>>> d = {True: 2}
>>> d[1] = 5
>>> d
{True: 5}
```

Comment: This is one of the best examples I have seen. +1

Comment: nice one ;)....

Comment: Thanks bro for clearing this doubt @user2390182